# PowerBI Embedded - Formatting disappears on render

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a PowerBI report built in PowerBI desktop and displaying in a .net app using javascript.  We have basic cards with decimal values formatted as currencies or percentages (in the formatting ribbon in PowerBI desktop).  When the embedded report first displays in the web app, the formatting symbols ($, %) show for a split second and then disappear.  I've removed layout and any extra style sheets and javascripts from the page, but still get the behavior.  Have also set the localSettings in the JS config.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great solution, but a potential workaround would be to format the values using the [FORMAT function](https://dax.guide/format/) which changes them to be text strings in the format you define rather than numeric values that get formatted however it decides.

For example, if you have a `[measure]` you can define another one like this:

```
measure_formatted = FORMAT ( [measure], "$ #,0.00")
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and have looked at it.  It seems like it will be painful since I'm trying to meet a customers exact expectations.  It's also so frustrating that I literally see the formatting for a second and then it disappears.  I'm not marking as solution, but I have up-voted you.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, Power BI formatting is a bit underdeveloped compared to, say, Tableau. This is indeed a workaround rather than a true solution.